# Expand category when click on row

Tags: jquery, xpages, viewpanel

I have a viewPanel and a categorized view in Xpages, when user click the category link the category is expanded.

I would like to create a jquery function that will expand the category also when the user click the row (TR),  is this possible using jquery or in another way?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Yes, the TR must have an identifier ID, then with ajax u have to get the data of this ID, after that, create the 'expanded' content and insert data into the expanded content.

Answer (score 0):

`dojo.behavior` can be used to add functionality to parts of an XPage based on, for example, the class of an HTML element. There's a blog post on [Jesse Gallagher's blog](https://frostillic.us/f.nsf/posts/using-dojo.behavior) and an example of using it to make categories look like nested sections on [Tommy Valand's blog](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/xpages-make-categorized-views-behave.html)